# Compute multiple faces connected at vertices from normal vectors

Tags: matlab, rotation, polygon, patch

I have a set of 8 normal vectors in 3D space. I need to plot a cuboid with lateral wings from these vectors:

[image: see picture]

whereas vectors 4 to 6 are just the negatives (opposite sides) of the first three and the last two vectors are identical to the first one and make up the wings.

The goal is to plot this object with each surface having a different color so that I can count the pixels of each color afterward for different sets of normal vectors (i.e. determining the visibility of partially obstructed surfaces).

I have found the `patch` function which can plot polygons with individual colors and takes the coordinates of the vertices for input. However, I do know the dimension of each surface, but the coordinates of the vertices need to be somehow calculated for each set of normals vectors. Any suggestions on how to approach this task?

**EDIT**
I may have found a solution: I just noticed that `view` allows defined azimuth and elevation angles and thus "rotation" of the object. With the compution of azimuth and elevation from the normal vectors, the calculation of the vertices becomes unnecessary.

Comment: Will the shapes always be in this form? i.e. 3 rectangles (one partially obscured) and 2 parallelograms?

Comment: @Wolfie The picture I posted should just provide the view from _one_ viewing angle. Since the normal vectors change from set to set, the perspective and shape of the faces will be different each time.